# How do I move navigation bar?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, navigation-key

I am using a Windows 10 phone. The Windows "return to desktop" logo is positioned immediately below the space bar and I often hit it by mistake. How can I move this bottom navigation bar to the top of my screen?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any way to change the location, however, if you swipe up, from the bottom of the screen, the soft buttons will toggle whether hidden or visible.

Comment: Thanks very much Rowland. I don't have any experience of soft buttons toggling when hidden but when I tried your suggestion of swiping up, my bottom tool bar completely disappeared so you have totally cured my problem. A big handshake and thank you.